# How to create workflow & submit data using infopath form?

Tags: workflow, infopath, custom-actions, workflow-activity

I have designed the Form in InfoPath.

I want to submit the form's data in my Sharepoint site. Sothat the supervisor(the higher level)person can check the details and he can Approve/Reject the submited data.

For Ex: If I submit request for leave, the manager can approve/reject my leaves.

How can do this using WorkFlow ?

Where I have to create Workflow on CustomList or on the Site ?

Answer (score 2):

You can publish the form to a SharePoint forms library. People create a new item in the library with that form and save the item in the library. For the approval side of things, create a custom workflow in SharePoint Designer or use the out of the box three state workflow that comes with SharePoint.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have InfoPath set up to be integrated in SharePoint (configure from Central Admin, SharePoint 2010 Enterprise is required), you can create your list first, with say a column for approval status, and then click the button on the ribbon called "Customize Form" that has an InfoPath icon. This will allow you to edit your form which submits directly to that list. From there, add your workflow with SharePoint designer for your logical functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I do that I create a field called 'IsSubmitted' on the form ,when submitted I set IsSubmitted=true.

Now publish the form in the form library.Before that also create a submit data connection to the particular library.Now from form librarry settings create the workflow (trigger it when new item is created).

Answer (score 2):

You can create a workflow by browser ( ex.  I.e )  or by SP Designer, to send the entry , to manager by email ...
Then manager will find the url of the  form and open it from email. And change the status field...
 You  should keep a field as status and keep the default value as submitted. 
So any time a form is filled up, it's status will be submitted automatically. 
Then  Manager will  change the status according to his criteria...

Steps are---
Create list
Create workflow
Modify the form  in infopath , once happy with everything...

Hope it will help...

Answer (score -2):

Here's is a video tutorial that might help you.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zw7HLXGCtNA

Comment: Please try to avoid link only answers as things like videos and blog posts may be moved or deleted making your answer less useful. We try to encourage posters to give at least a high level summary so that people who find this page months from now are able to get some help even if the video is removed.